# Ruby merge sort -- how does this recursive function work?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I'm doing an assignment writing a recursive merge sort algorithm in Ruby. I'm trying to break this down piece by piece in order to be able to wrap my head around it. What I have so far is trying to accomplish the "divide" step until there is only one element left in each array.

```
a = [5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 8]

def divide(arr)
  return arr if arr.length < 2
    else
      arr1 = puts divide(arr[0..arr.length/2-1])
      arr2 = puts divide(arr[arr.length/2..arr.length])
end
```

I would think the output would be:

```
[5] [8]
```

But it prints out:

```
5
2

4
6

1
7

3
8
```

How does it work?

Comment: Man I am so confused, got rid of the puts and it just return [8] now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two problems.

First, the `else` statement has no effect, it's not how you do `if else` in Ruby.

Second, if `a.length < 2` is `false` then your method will return `nil`. `puts` returns `nil`, `x = nil` returns `nil`.

I've added some prints to demonstrate how your code works, I hope it'll help:

```
$level = 0

def divide(arr)
  return arr if arr.length < 2

  $level += 1

  puts "Working with array #{arr}"

  arr1 = divide(arr[0..arr.length/2-1])
  puts "Level = #{$level} arr1 = #{arr1}"
  arr2 = divide(arr[arr.length/2..arr.length])
  puts "Level = #{$level} arr2 = #{arr2}"

  $level -= 1

  nil
end

divide([5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 8])
```

The output:

```
Working with array [5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 8]
Working with array [5, 2, 4, 6]
Working with array [5, 2]
Level = 3 arr1 = [5]
Level = 3 arr2 = [2]
Level = 3 arr1 = 
Working with array [4, 6]
Level = 4 arr1 = [4]
Level = 4 arr2 = [6]
Level = 4 arr2 = 
Level = 4 arr1 = 
Working with array [1, 7, 3, 8]
Working with array [1, 7]
Level = 6 arr1 = [1]
Level = 6 arr2 = [7]
Level = 6 arr1 = 
Working with array [3, 8]
Level = 7 arr1 = [3]
Level = 7 arr2 = [8]
Level = 7 arr2 = 
Level = 7 arr2 =
```

Comment: So lost in the rabbit hole right now. I've never struggled this hard before with anything in my life. What I'm seeing is it only divides arr1 until it can't and then arr2 doesn't end up working with the last 4 numbers like I had hoped. Not only that the numbers are disappearing and that's not how a merge sort is supposed to work. This is going to be the death of me.

Comment: It would probably help to explain *why* the `else` is useless (it is being interpreted as the `else` of an implicit `rescue` block). By the way, @JacobMoore: you should get into the habit of reading warnings; your code generates the following warning: "warning: else without rescue is useless", which is precisely what Danil is talking about.